# Find a relation between a,b and c

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

$ a,b,c\in \Bbb R$

$2x_1+2x_2+3x_3=a$

$3x_1-x_2+5x_3=b$

$x_1-3x_2+2x_3=c$

if  a,b and c is a solution of this linear equation system find the relation between a,b and c

I dont understand the question. without knowing a,b and c is a solution of eq.syst. I found

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        2 & 2 & 3 &a \\
        3 & -1 & 5&b \\
        0 & 0 & 0 &a+c-b\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

and therefore $b=a+c$

when I use a,b and c as a solution

$2a+2b+3c=a$

$3a-b+5c=b$

$a-3b+2c=c$

reduced row echolon form is

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

it gives a=0 b=0 c=0

Comment: $b=a+c$ answers the question.

Comment: Thanks. Why does it state a solution is a,b,c since we dont need it?

Comment: The wording of this problem is confusing.  They mean that $a, b, c$ are numbers for which this system is satisfied for some values of $x_1, x_2, x_3$, and not that $x_1=a, x_2=b, x_3=c$ is a solution.